# SpriteRenderer.sprite doesn't changing images

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a little problem while changing an image using SpriteRenderer component.

When my mouse is over the sprite, the image have to change and the problem is that it's removing the current image but not putting the right one.

Before I draw the first images with that and it's working :

```
GameObject tile = Instantiate(Resources.Load("TilePrefab")) as GameObject;
```

But not in this case :

```
void OnMouseOver () {

    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Resources.Load("TileHoverPrefab") as Sprite;
}
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved ! I was loading a prefab and not a sprite....